# Hide item rows(whole row) in list view based on user group membership through javascript/SP services in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, listview, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

How to hide full item row based on group membership of user (or a column value). I have this list view:

[image]

I want to hide complete item row based on user membership in department groups (SharePoint groups containing users of different departments Legal, Project Mngmt etc). So that each depart employees view their entries only. I do not want to use Target audience on list view webpart.

I have used this code to hide fields in form but how to use it to whole item row in list view?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
    userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
    async: false,
       completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
       var flag = ($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='LegalDepartment']").length == 1);
       if (!flag)
        {
            //To Hide Column Header
            $("nobr:contains('User ID')").closest('tr').hide();
        }
       }
    })
})
```

How is it possible through SP services/javascript?

Comment: you can use item level permissions to hide rows

Comment: @MuhammadObaidullahAther I do not want to use item level permissions.. I simply need to "hide" entire row based on single column value. How do I, where do I get relative `<tr>` reference it so that I can hide it in my javascript code

Answer (score 0):

So far I have understood your requirement, There can be two approaches:
**First approach** is setting item level permissions. This can be achieved using REST API as well as JSOM. Please check [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164215/set-list-item-level-permission-in-jsom-javascript-object-model)

**Second Approach** is to get current user group membership to get the groups that user is member of (please check [here](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-get-the-user-groups-of-the-current-logged-in-user-using-javascript-in-sharepoint-2013/) for JSOM code). Once groups are fetched, these can be matched with desired colum e.g. `Department` or `Assigned to` and list view DOM can be manipulated accordingly to show/hide each row.

> I would prefer first approach as that strictly follows SharePoint security principles to remove user's rights over a particular item. Second, approach however feels unsecure as if user manages to show the row assigned to other department (that he is not member of) using browser tools or whatever, he can still edit that row depending upon his rights on list/library as a whole. 
>   you might need to create a SharePoint workflow to set item level permissions based on desired columns on item creation event. Please check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153979/how-to-set-item-level-permission-using-sharepoint-designer-2013-work-flow) for details.
>   Hope this helps.

Comment: you can use JS link and show/hide a row based on Particular column's value and get current user's group using custom code.